# GeneratorOf<T> Cannot find an initializer Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

My attempts to understand Generators and Sequences lead me to an idea to implement a Fibonacci sequence. This works perfect:

```
struct FibonacciGenerator : GeneratorType
{
    typealias Element = Int

    var current = 0, nextValue = 1

    mutating func next() -> Int?
    {
        let ret = current
        current = nextValue
        nextValue = nextValue + ret
        return ret
    }
}


struct FibonacciSequence : SequenceType
{
    typealias Generator = FibonacciGenerator

    func generate() -> Generator
    {
        return FibonacciGenerator()
    }
}
```

Then I decide to use SequenceOf and GeneratorOf to do the same, but I stuck on GeneratorOf that gives me an error "cannot find an initializer for type 'GeneratorOF' that accepts an argument list of type '(() -> _)'" for next code.

```
var current = 0
var nextValue = 1

var fgOf = GeneratorOf{
    let ret = current
        current = nextValue
        nextValue = nextValue + ret
        return ret
}
```

[image]

But if I wrap it into a function it works fine:

```
    func getFibonacciGenerator() -> GeneratorOf<Int>
{

    var current = 0
    var nextValue = 1

    return GeneratorOf{
        let ret = current
        current = nextValue
        nextValue = nextValue + ret
        return ret
    }
}
```

Why it works differently? Is this some Xcode bug or I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure used in the initializer of `GeneratorOf` has the type
`() -> T?`, and in

```
var fgOf = GeneratorOf {
    let ret = current
    current = nextValue
    nextValue = nextValue + ret
    return ret
}
```

the compiler cannot infer what `T` is. You can either make the block signature
explicit

```
var fgOf = GeneratorOf { () -> Int? in
    let ret = current
    current = nextValue
    nextValue = nextValue + ret
    return ret
}
```

or specify the type of the generator with

```
var fgOf = GeneratorOf<Int> { 
    let ret = current
    current = nextValue
    nextValue = nextValue + ret
    return ret
}
```

In your last example

```
func getFibonacciGenerator() -> GeneratorOf<Int>
{
    // ...
    return GeneratorOf {
        // ...
        return ret
    }
}
```

it works because the type is inferred from the context (i.e.
from the return type of `getFibonacciGenerator()`).